# How to use social sharing in Ionic 3?

Tags: ionic3, ionic-native

[image: ionic version]

[image]

I build app using Ionic 3. My app needed social sharing. I installed social sharing plugin from here https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/social-sharing/
But error show

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: When we adding in app.module.ts show error "SocialSharingOriginal" is not assignable to type provider.
See screenshot above.

Comment: What is the version of `cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing` plugin ? and also `@ionic-native/social-sharing` version in package.json

Comment: <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" spec="^5.4.4" />

Comment: `@ionic-native/social-sharing` version ?

Comment: How to find this version ?

Comment: You can find it in your package.json file

Comment: "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^5.0.0",

Comment: see my answer and confirm is it working for you

Comment: Okay, I will check

Comment: Yes, Working fine

Comment: please mark the answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You installed the latest `@ionic-native/social-sharing` (v5+)

Fallback `@ionic-native/social-sharing` to v4+. The issue will be fixed.

Follow these steps:

`npm uninstall --save @ionic-native/social-sharing`

`npm install --save @ionic-native/social-sharing@4.12.0`